# doc.meteor.com does not work well with Mac Safari 7.0.1?

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I've been using Mac (Mavericks) Safari to lookup docs.meteor.com but of late, Safari was not able to read the site. The location bar keeps refreshing and no page appears.

I think the latest 0.7.0.1 may have broke it. Any one experiencing the same issue?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. Safari (Mavericks)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there is a known problem as discussed in this thread at meteor-talk google group:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/ZzQVdcdz33Y/discussion

It seems to work when dev tools is open and now work when it is closed.